# C# Populating a comboBox with a List<String> created by user imput in the same WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, list, combobox, textbox

I want to Populate a comboBox with a List created by user input in the same WPF window, but it isn't working

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 //Here I populate the ComboBox with the List 

 private void Window_Initialized_1(object sender, EventArgs e){


        List<string> listaCiudad = EstudioService.obtenerCiudad();

        this.ciudadesCBx.Items.Clear();

        foreach (String ciudad in listaCiudad){
            this.ciudadesCBx.Items.Add(ciudad);
        }
    }

    //Here I get the user input from a textBox called ciudadTxt
    //by clicking in the button named agregarCiudadBtn

    private void agregarCiudadBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EstudioService.agregarCiudad(ciudadTxt.Text);

    }
```

public class EstudioService

```
 private static List<String> listaCiudad = new List<string>();


    public static void agregarCiudad(String ciudad)
    {
        listaCiudad.Add(ciudad);

    }

    public static List<String> obtenerCiudad()
    {
        return listaCiudad;
    }
```

Comment: If you for testing put `this.ciudadesCBx.Items.Add(ciudadTxt.Text)` inside `agregarCiudadBtn_Click` method, will it populate combo box?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Put that observable list in model and bind it to Combo Box. It doesn't matter if it is empty. Later on when you make your input just add that new input in the observable list collection and Combo Box should pick it up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, code adding `List` values to combobox in the `Window_Initialized_1` eevent, I believe this event triggered(in your case) only when form is initialized (correct me if that is not the case).

Move below logic to `agregarCiudad` method.

```
this.ciudadesCBx.Items.Clear();

oreach (String ciudad in listaCiudad){
     this.ciudadesCBx.Items.Add(ciudad);
}
```

so your method should look like

```
public static void agregarCiudad(String ciudad)
{
     this.ciudadesCBx.Items.Clear();
    listaCiudad.Add(ciudad);
    ciudadesCBx.Items.AddRange(listaCiudad);

}
```